# Caffe deploy.prototxt with multiple inputs of different dimensions

Tags: input, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, dimensions

I have a network in Caffe that accepts multiple image inputs (possibly of different dimensions) and uses them as separate blobs for the initial part of the network.

For the training phase, I implemented this by creating a HDF5 database as suggested in the documentation.

However, for the deploy phase, I need to replace the data layer from the training phase with an input layer, and specify the dimensions of the input blob.

For a single blob, this is done with the shape property of input_param. How can I do it in this case, where I have multiple blobs, possibly of different dimensions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L66-L69) you'll see that `input` and `input_shape` has the property of `repeated`:

> ```
> // DEPRECATED. See InputParameter. The input blobs to the network.
> repeated string input = 3;
> // DEPRECATED. See InputParameter. The shape of the input blobs.
> repeated BlobShape input_shape = 8;
> ```

Which means you can have *several* such entries:

```
name: "AnAmazingNetWithMultipleInputs_ThankYouShai_IwillForeverBeInYourDebt"
input: "first_input_1x3x127x127"
input_shape { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 127 dim: 127 }
input: "second_input_2x4x224x224"
input_shape { dim: 2 dim: 4 dim: 224 dim: 224 }
# I hope you can take it from here ;)
```

---

If you look even closer at the relevant section of [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L66-L69), you'll notice that this form of "input shape declaration" is DEPRECATED.
A better way is to use [`"Input"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/input.html) layer:

```
layer {
  type: "Input"
  name: "one_input_layer"
  top: "first_input_1x3x127x127"
  shape { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 127 dim: 127 }
  top: "second_input_2x4x224x224"
  shape { dim: 2 dim: 4 dim: 224 dim: 224 }
}
```

You can also have a different `"Input"` layer for each input, if you find it easier to understand/read.

Comment: Thank you! I should have thought of using multiple input layers! One query: if I use top and shape repeatedly, must there be exactly one shape after every top? How does it establish the mapping?

Comment: I suppose by the order of appearance

Comment: Thank you, @Shai, that worked. However, there seems to be a small error: shape is a property of input_param, not the Input layer directly, I think. I got an error when I tried to use it as in your second example, which was corrected by using input_param.